# How can I apply transitions to the same elements but in different states of :hover

Tags: css

I'm building a responsive slider and I have a navigation arrow on each side. I'd like the arrows to be hidden unless the user hovers over them in which case they'll have a smooth transition from `opacity:0` to `opacity: 1` which I like. I'd then like my fa-icons to have a smooth scale transition when hovered over (again, while the user is still inside of the slider) but I'm running into an issue where the icon `:hover` transition (scale) doesn't occur. The scale transition was working before I decided to do the hidden controls design so I know it's not that the transitions themselves aren't working, I just think there's a hierarchy conflict of some kind that I can't seem to solve.

I know I could solve this by doing a mouse-in and mouse-out animation in Javascript and just separate effects by doing transition on one and animations on the other, but I'm curious to know if there's a CSS solution to this that I'm just not able to figure out?

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

.slideShowContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #414141;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: rgba(60, 64, 67, 0.3) 0px 1px 2px 0px, rgba(60, 64, 67, 0.15) 0px 1px 3px 1px;
}

.fa-chevron-right {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 2.3vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 5%;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 1s linear;
}

.fa-chevron-left {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 2.3vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 5%;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 1s linear;
}

.fa-chevron-right:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: transform 1s linear;
}

.fa-chevron-left:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: transform 1s linear;
}

.slideShowContainer:hover .fa-chevron-right {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}

.slideShowContainer:hover .fa-chevron-left {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<body>
  <div class="slideShowContainer">
    <i id="slideRight" class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    <i id="slideLeft" class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few problems:

1. Your CSS was getting overridden on specificity, so you didn't necessarily always have the `transition` property you intended
2. Changing transition properties on state changes often won't work-- it's better, if at all possible, to collapse all properties you want transitioned into a single comma-separated declaration
3. Critically, you were trying to transition `scale`, but that is just the transform being applied to the `transform` property-- there is no CSS `scale` property

I fixed these in the below snippet and it now works as expected.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

.slideShowContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #414141;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: rgba(60, 64, 67, 0.3) 0px 1px 2px 0px, rgba(60, 64, 67, 0.15) 0px 1px 3px 1px;
}

.fa-chevron-right {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 2.3vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 5%;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: transform 1s linear, opacity 0.3s linear;
}

.fa-chevron-left {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 2.3vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 5%;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 1s linear, opacity 0.3s linear;
}

.fa-chevron-right:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.fa-chevron-left:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.slideShowContainer:hover .fa-chevron-right {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slideShowContainer:hover .fa-chevron-left {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<body>
  <div class="slideShowContainer">
    <i id="slideRight" class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    <i id="slideLeft" class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I realized after I posted that I was trying to transition the scale and not the transform and felt stupid so I updated the question but obviously it was more of a complex issue than that so I'm glad somebody could figure it out! Much appreciated! :)